# Unable to boot - Non-system disk or disk error

Tags: boot

I wanted to convert my HP ProBook 4520s into a Chromebook. I did install on a USB Drive CloudReady from neverware.com

I have been able to boot up once from the USB Drive and follow the installation instructions. But it stopped when I choose the option CloudReady only.

I open the BIOS and run system diagnostics and the conclusion is that hard disk is ok.

Then, here are the scenarios I get:

1. Insert USB Drive and hit F9 (boot device options). It takes about 1-2 minutes and I have the following boot options:

   - optical disk Drive
   - notebook hard Drive
   - notebook Ethernet

   No matter which boot option I choose, I get the message:

   > Non-system disk or disk error replace and strike any key when ready
2. Start computer without USB Drive, I get the message:

   > Non-system disk or disk error replace and strike any key when ready
3. Open BIOS. Go in system configuration. Go to boot options. Go to boot legacy boot order. Put USB hard Drive first. Save. Exit. Computer will start and show CloudReady and then black screen... to eventually restart and do the same thing.

Why will it not boot with CloudReady, or how can I overcome the non-system disk or disk error message?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to update the BIOS first. I assume there is a compatibility issue with how newer operating systems boot and work. A [4420s](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1_k-BQe8KYUdkQcH-5vKlgS7Vlj7Y6_KsBkVRcb7MqKk/edit#slide=id.ga9588ab56_131) of the same generation is said to work though and should even be able to boot via UEFI which is surprising because I remember a talk by an HP employee at a Linux conference who said that models shipped before Windows 8 or before 2012 are not UEFI feature complete and this model appears to be from 2010. Here is what Cloud Ready says about UEFI:

> 3: To UEFI boot on this machine (for dual boot or other purposes) Boot to BIOS and enable UEFI Boot Mode. Then, initiate USB boot from your installer and select “Boot From EFI File > [select USB device] > efi > boot > bootx64.efi”

They also make a statement about compatible Wi-Fi chips. I suggest you contact Cloud Ready for support. After all, it's a product they are trying to sell also to enterprises to refurbish such old machines. Another option are images by [arnoldthebat.co.uk](https://arnoldthebat.co.uk/).

Comment: Trier UEFI boot mode. Nothing is happening. I will contact cloudready and will go check arnoldthebat.co.uk.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and found a solution to it.
My Computer was archaic notebook HP 6530b
I tried to run ChromeOS from USB stick and it ran ok.
So I wiped out HDD, flashed ChromeOS to HDD and ... "non system disk or disk error"
I tried to wipe out disk partitions using live ubuntu and gparted but it does not help. It really seemed, that ChomeOS installer creates all necessary partitions but it or BIOS fails to create proper BIOS boot entry.
I was able to boot to ChromeOS only manually by selecting proper EFI boot file from boot menu - Boot from EFI file.

Upgrading BIOS to latest version helped, although getting it was not so easy.
I used Rufus to create freedos bootable USB disk
Then I copied ROMPAQ folder from HP/Compaq 65XX FW updater installer (extracted folder in root of C: drive):
https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp49001-49500/sp49264.exe
to freedos bootable USB and after booting from USB key I ran the ROMPAQ updater from DOS prompt.

After updating FW to F.14 on next boot I was able to boot to ChromeOS without any problem and any user intervention.